# Load a tabBarController from a UIButton in a subview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on an app where i have a view controller that contains a view in that view i have a button that when pressed i would like it to load my tabViewController.

I trying to get a splash screen to load before my app so i can do some downloading and parsing of data before i load my tabViewController because the data im putting the data into a tableView that is in the tabViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here's a good example on creating a splash screen
   http://adeem.me/blog/2009/06/22/creating-splash-screen-tutorial-for-iphone/
2. I would suggest that you look into using performSelector and launching a background thread
   before putting your splash screen up to populate/parse the data.

Comment: I actually found that tutorial last night after i posted this question i am still working on implementing it. Do you know of an example that has actual calculations going on in the splash screen?